# Can't change base memory in Virtualbox

Tags: memory, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I need to increase the allocated base memory in Virtualbox to boost the performance. I change it just fine with the machine turned off, but as soon as I start the machine, it reverts back to the old memory. This happens if I both try to increase or decrease the allocated memory, it always returns back to the original value(2048) as soon as I start the machine. It is as if the memory is overwritten. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhhaa..

I dont know if this is a general solution, but in my case, because this machine is using **Vagrant** the solution to my problem turned out to have been in the **VagrantFile** containing settings for this machine.

In my **VagrantFile** I found this:

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = true
     vb.memory = "2048"
   end
```

Once the memory line was removed, I was able to change the memory from the settings as desired.